# Code not working when deployed on hosting server but works in local

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is working correctly in local but when I deployed it to hosting server I am getting the following error

```
System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'date'.
```

I have checked the internet and based on solutions I found I have checked the below cases and they are fine:

1. Generally occurs due to misspelled column names, hence one should recheck that.
2. If the column names in the Control is correct then check what columns your query is returning and the column that you have specified to the control exists or not.
3. Many times due to exceptions nothing is returned in that case check the code for such issues.

I have checked all the above and they are all working in local

Part of the code in the page where the error is as follows:

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="phone" SortExpression="phone" />

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="date">
                     <ItemTemplate >
                     <%#Eval("date")%>
                     </ItemTemplate>

                 </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:BoundField DataField="time" HeaderText="time" SortExpression="time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="street" HeaderText="street" SortExpression="street" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="street2" HeaderText="street2" SortExpression="street2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="area" HeaderText="area" SortExpression="area" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" SortExpression="city" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dstreet" HeaderText="dstreet" SortExpression="dstreet" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dstreet2" HeaderText="dstreet2" SortExpression="dstreet2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="darea2" HeaderText="darea2" SortExpression="darea2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dcity2" HeaderText="dcity2" SortExpression="dcity2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="typeoftrip" HeaderText="typeoftrip" SortExpression="typeoftrip" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"         ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringName %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [customerdetails] WHERE [customerid] = @original_customerid" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [customerdetails] ([name], [email], [phone], [date], [time], [street], [street2], [area], [city], [dstreet], [dstreet2], [darea2], [dcity2], [typeoftrip]) VALUES (@name, @email, @phone, @date, @time, @street, @street2, @area, @city, @dstreet, @dstreet2, @darea2, @dcity2, @typeoftrip)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM customerdetails where [date] > dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(d,-1, getdate())))) and  [date] < dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(d, 1, getdate()))))" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [customerdetails] SET [name] = @name, [email] = @email, [phone] = @phone, [time] = @time, [street] = @street, [street2] = @street2, [area] = @area, [city] = @city, [dstreet] = @dstreet, [dstreet2] = @dstreet2, [darea2] = @darea2, [dcity2] = @dcity2, [typeoftrip] = @typeoftrip WHERE [customerid] = @original_customerid ">
```

Comment: Are you sure the data coming out of the database in production has all the same fields as the data coming out of the database on your development box?

Comment: @Bert Evans, yes it is same .

Comment: How about your web.config? Are you publishing a web.config with connection strings pointing to your local database instead of the production database?

Comment: Yes ,the connection string is fine ,as there are other insert,update ,delete functionalities in the website that are working fine.The connection string is pointing to the database i created on the hosting server.Even this code,will show an empty gird view(nothing is shown,but no error) for older dates,it is only when i inserted and entry with todays date that i got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working ,i commented all bound field and template field and for the girdview i kept AutoGenerateColumns="True" ,so all the columns were displayed and grid view is working

This isn't proper solution to problem but what i found out after searching on the net is that may be it is caused due to different IIS server ,my hosting IIS server and my local are different ,so may be becuase of that it is caused .

Comment: Glad to see you did it, but I can't digest IIS being the reason for this problem.

Comment: @dotNET I checked a lot on the net ,many people posted a similar question,but there is no concrete answer ,for some if problem is in BoundField they weretold to change to ItemTemplate and it was working for them ,but in my case i changed to both Boundfield and Item Template for 'date' ,but it didnt work for me